# Is it illegal for an adult to contact a minor asking for parent info?

Tags: minor, adult

By an ex-friend's parent I was sent a message saying “remove this video and have a parent contact me, if not I will find a parent contact and tell them what things you are posting”.

What I posted was a video saying I don’t like my ex-best friend  who was attempting to control me and that I have better friends now. Also shall I add I have no clue how this man got my number assuming my ex-friend and I deleted each other's numbers and have no way of knowing each other's number?

Comment: They are not "asking for parent info". Are you a minor? If so have you asked your parents about this?

Comment: What country is this in?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is legal that this person sends you a message at all or are you asking about the legality of the threat their are making in the message?

Answer (score 4):

In the [united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states), the [First Amendment](https://www.archives.gov/founding-docs/bill-of-rights-transcript#toc-amendment-i) right to freedom of speech generally protects an adult who contacts a minor seeking contact information for her parents.

Although there are [several exceptions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/in-the-usa-can-treason-be-protected-by-the-first-amendment/56002#56002) to the right to free speech, this speech falls within none of them.

Comment: What does the First protect "an adult who contacts a minor seeking contact information for her parents" _from_? In other words, if not for the First, would the adult be in any legal jeopardy? Why?

Comment: I don't know of any law that would be implicated here. This is a case of the First Amendment acting as a prophylactic rather than an affirmative defense.

Answer (score 2):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Notwithstanding the title and the OP's quote saying different things, i.e.

> Is it illegal for an adult to contact a minor asking for parent info?

Is not the same as:

> ...have a parent contact me, if not I will find a parent contact...

**There is no law (that I can find) making either action unlaw in this context.**

Answer (score 1):

### Quite legal in [germany](/questions/tagged/germany)

No law prohibits an adult to ask a child to get in contact with their parents. In fact, at times it might be imperative to do so - for example, if a teacher needs to tell about the misconduct of the pupil, or the neighbor suffered a harm (like a broken flowerpot) from the child's action.

In the first case, the teacher usually already has a number and requiring them to tell their parents to contact the teacher is to make it easier on the kid - if the teacher calls because the kid didn't fess up, the outcome might be more severe.

In the later case, the neighbor might have a legal case they can pursue to have the parents to pay up for the damage caused by the parents not supervising their child. So the request is not only justified, it also is possibly of legal consequence, since the parents (or guardians) have some obligations.

Now here comes the kicker: In Germany, there are laws against insulting. Yes, defamation of character and heavy insults are lesser felonies under [§185 StGB](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__185.html) in Germany with up to one-year imprisonment, or a real felony if done very public - like on any social media. At least for Adults. Minors above 14 (and technically young adults up to 21) can be prosecuted using the same paragraphs but much less severe punishments, depending on age, while children of less than 14 get an entry into a register (for use if they offend after 14 - their punishment is augmented then) and a stern talking to at best.