Copyright Fair Use: Is using the phrase "Courtesy of" legally acceptable when no permission has been given?
When quoting content under copyright fair use, is it legally acceptable (in English) to use the words "Courtesy of ACME Inc.", even if no permission has been granted?
To me, the words "courtesy of" imply that permission has been granted.  But I'm thinking that implication is likely irrelevant in the eyes of law, and that using the words "courtesy of" is likely fine, regardless of whether permission is granted.
Is my hunch legally founded or incorrect?
I'm interested in answers for any and all jurisdictions.
Inspired by this Law Stack Exchange QA: Does this Super User answer on Stack Exchange constitute fair use or copyright infringement?

The language itself is probably ambiguous: "courtesy of" clearly indicates the source, but there is one sense of the phase the mean "with the permission of" and another sense of the phrase that merely means "possible as a result of the efforts of". As the answer by Jen indicates, however, the distinction may not be very legally relevant.

@ohwilleke Yes, the legal relevance is my curiosity, and any meaning ambiguity may make it more complicated (see my comment to Jen under their helpful answer).  BTW, which dictionary did you use to source those meanings?  My favourite dictionaries provide different meanings.

I didn't look it up in a dictionary. I relied upon my experience as a native speaker of American English who has seen the phrase used by other native speakers of American English in both senses of that phrase.

@ohwilleke Ah, I've actually never heard it used the second way (nor does my dictionary mention that use), but I don't doubt you've seen it, as Americans still haven't quite mastered the English language. ;)  (that's just a little light humour)

The second sense comes up quite often, for example, in academia. "Courtesy of Einstein, we know that . . .", "Courtesy of Euler, we know that . . .", "Courtesy of Freud, we distinguish between . . .", "Courtesy of Shakespeare, we say that . . ." It is almost like ancestor worship, although it isn't restricted to dead people, and goes along with the academic concern about attribution of ideas, as opposed to ownership of IP.

@ohwilleke Oh, you're absolutely right.  I completely forgot about that use.  Thanks for the examples... those got the neurons firing!

No, very clearly not. What would I know, who worked in publishing for less than 20 years… and still, 'Courtesy of' always and solely means 'with permission from…'.
When anyone can find an instance of 'Courtesy of' meaning anything like 'possible as a result of the efforts of…' that one might like to Post that instance.
When anyone can find an instance of the Answer by Jen indicating anything legally relevant, that one might like to Post an explanation.

Sideline: why not instead use another phrasing? "source:" or "authorship:"

Fair use does not necessarily require attribution and does not dictate any particular form of attribution. Of course, the method of attribution and/or linking to an original source can inform the fair use analysis, but that is a case-by-case assessment, alongside all the other factors.
Where attribution intersects clearly with copyright law is when a person is making a licenced use of a work, and the licence calls for a particular form of attribution.
Fair use is about what would otherwise be an infringement — unlicensed use.

Interesting. Thanks.  Not that I would do or recommend it, but regarding a fair use quote, could someone then indicate consent was provided when none was provided?  Or does that get into other areas of the law?

@EndAntisemiticHate It would probably be some other area, e.g. fraud or defamation (e.g. the copyright owner's reputation is impacted if people think they're associated with you).

It would not be fraud or defamation, unless we added some crazy facts for the purpose of manufacturing fraud or defamation.

It could be false advertisement.

If it were true, how could that help, Jen?
Why not explain how you see 'fair use' and 'courtesy of' as in any way similar?

@EndAntisemiticHate Indicating you have consent when you don't is probably more likely to get the copyright holder to sic a lawyer on you, since now you're implying that they actively approve of whatever your use is, rather than just ignoring it.

In the United States, the First Amendment makes it "legally acceptance" to say "courtesy of" in the absence of permission to copy a piece of copyrighted material -- at least in the sense that it is not an offense to say that phrase.
However, that does not mean that using that phrase (or any other disclaimer of authorship) makes it "legally acceptable" to copy a copyrighted work in the absence of permission to do so. Infringement is still infringement, even if you acknowledge that you did not create the work, even if you give credit to the author, and even if you say that you do not intend to infringe.

I have no reason to doubt your claim (and many reasons to believe you are much more knowledgeable than myself on the topic!).  Can you add support as to why it's the First Amendment that makes it legally acceptable?

It's annoying, but the analytically correct answer is that you're asking the wrong question. We don't generally ask whether speech is protected under the First Amendment; we assume it is protected and then ask if there's some reason to conclude otherwise. And there's only a very small number of cases where it isn't protected. See my answer here: https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/56001/in-the-usa-can-treason-be-protected-by-the-first-amendment

@EndAntisemiticHate In free countries, anything that isn't forbidden is legal. The First Amendment just prohibits the government from forbidding a lot of things related to speech (but not all). Unless you find a law that says "it's forbidden to say courtesy of", then it's legal. But as this answer states, you can say "courtesy of" all you want, it doesn't change whether you are or aren't infringing copyright (or other IP laws).

It should be “legally acceptable” not “legally acceptance” but SO won’t let me make a 2 character edit and I don’t want to change things just hit that limit.

france
Not copyright infringement
"Fair use" does not exist in France, but something similar is at §3 of article L122-5 of the intellectual property code:

Lorsque l'oeuvre a été divulguée, l'auteur ne peut interdire :
(...)
3° Sous réserve que soient indiqués clairement le nom de l'auteur et la source :
a) Les analyses et courtes citations justifiées par le caractère critique, polémique, pédagogique, scientifique ou d'information de l'oeuvre à laquelle elles sont incorporées (...)


Once a work has been published, its author cannot forbid
(...)
3° Under the condition that the name of the author and the source be clearly indicated:
a) Analyses and short citations justified by an interest of criticism, debate, pedagogy, science or information, of the work within which it is incorporated (...)

Assuming for the sake of argument that the test for paragraph 3(a) is satisfied, there is no copyright violation if the citation requirements of 3° are satisfied.
Probably not defamation
A "courtesy of" mention can be understood as an assertion that the copyright holder gave permission to reproduce the work. That is a factual statement (and a false one, per our hypothesis).
However it is not enough that the statement be false to be defamatory; it has to "impunge on the honor or consideration of the person [or corporation] to which the action is attributed" (see article 29 of the law about press freedom).
In general that would not be true - giving permission to use stuff is widely seen as a nice thing to do. Even if it was defamatory, it usually would be very mild (and hence not worth pursuing legal action against). I can conceive some very specific cases where it would end up in court; for instance, if a prominent neo-Nazi publisher reproduces a quotation "courtesy of rabbi Hertzl" as part of some antisemitic screed, with the implication that rabbi Hertzl supports that publication.
Finally, a note about the practicalities of redress. Putting a monetary amount on non-tangible damage (reputational, emotional, etc.) is always difficult, but the French doctrine is (to a first approximation) "receipts or get out". A very common monetary award is the symbolic amount of €1; a very large portion of successful defamation cases (possibly more than half) end with that award. The more substantial redress in cases of defamation is judicial publication (where a newspaper who published a defamatory article is forced to publish the court’s judgment in the next issue with the same prominence as the original article), which would not be available in the US (where the first amendment prohibits compelled speech).

I guess if a politician was using some piece of art to promote their ideas and then said “courtesy of someone” (when they got no such permission), that someone could consider that the sentence implies they support those political ideas, and that it is defamation?

The phrase "courtesy of" can often be used with things that have an entity has supplied for use by "whomever", without implying any particular endorsement of any particular entity using the things.  If a business is replacing some office equipment and places it outside with a sign saying "FREE", and a member of neo-Nazi group recognizes that his group would have a use for it, the group might say the equipment is "courtesy of" the business, but that wouldn't imply any endorsement of the group by the business.  Likewise if a publisher is perceived as generally freindly toward independent...

...YouTube video producers who would present it in a good light.  In many cases, it is better for companies to unofficially tolerate such use while retaining the right to issue a Cease and Desist, than to license materials for a fee that would be insufficient to vet licensees to ensure they wouldn't use the material to present the publisher in a bad light.

No, rather clearly not.
Shortly, 'Courtesy of…' is meaningful only when it's 'Courtesy of Some One…'
To the extent that is meaningful, it implies both that Some One has given permission for this use, and more than likely Some One has given that permission without payment of any kind; free, gratis and for nothing.
